# jQuery resizable synch resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to ask if how can i fix the resizable jquery. What I want is if I resize the parent element it will also resize the children inside of the parent element. here's my current code:

```
<div id="img_holder" style="width:100px;height:120px;float:left;margin:5px;">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="thumbnail" style="text-decoration:none;height:120px;">
        <img src="suits.jpg" style="height:110px !important;" />
    </a>
</div>

$("#img_holder").resizable({alsoResize: "#img_holder a, #img_holder a img"});
```

here's the output when resizing
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The anchor and the images in your example have preset `height`, so they are not going to resize to a height larger than the set height. I also notice the img height is set using `!important`.

Comment: I removed the set height on all elements still the same.